# С расставленными знаками (вроде верными) предложение читаемо?

Tags: пунктуация

> Помимо того что Рим дал название целой эпохе христианского искусства –
>   романское (X–XIII столетия), есть и просто такое понятие: *римское
>   искусство*. Этот термин специалисты нередко употребляют, подразумевая
>   под ним целый набор качеств и свойств художественного произведения.
>   **Вместо того чтобы сказать: внимание к подробности, стремление к
>   идейной концентрации, натурализм, величие, монументальность (которая
>   может таиться и в маленькой вещичке) – это мощь и сила, лаконичность
>   высказывания, максимальная обращённость к зрителю, –** чтобы всего
>   этого не говорить, говорят просто: *римское искусство*.
>
> ---

Ребят, вышла книжка-то! Но цена кусается... Мне ещё  (06.01.2019) не прислали обещанный экземпляр (не знаю, кто чем помог и что от нас вообще оставил АСТ).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не, а астовцы те ещё молодцы (аннотация):

***древняя культура, кипящая современной жизнью***  О_о

Comment: Искусство древнего Рима, Рима царского периода, Рима периода Республики, Рима эпохи Возрождения — явления самостоятельные. Просто «римское искусство» охарактеризовать никому не удастся.

Comment: Поздравляю с выходом книги! Я в аннотации, похоже, "выпал"  союз *и*: с древней культурой и кипящей современной жизнью. А еще знак переноса забыли убрать.

Comment: Инга пишет: "А автора приговорить к трем годам усиленного чтения Розенталя! – М_Г аааа!!!!!!)))))) браво!!!" - только что. Зовёт читать следующие ея опусы. Возьмёмся? )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Рим дал название целой эпохе христианского искусства – романское

Романское - название эпохи?!

> Помимо того, что Рим дал название, ... есть ... понятие ...

Некое понятие существует помимо некоего действия? А Розенталя читали?

> Вместо того чтобы сказать: внимание к подробности, стремление к идейной концентрации, натурализм, величие, монументальность (которая может таиться и в маленькой вещичке) – это мощь и сила, лаконичность высказывания, максимальная обращённость к зрителю, – чтобы всего этого не говорить, говорят просто: римское искусство.

Вместо того, чтобы сказать: А это Б, говорят В?! Где логика? Я уж не говорю о том, что у вас между А и Б мало общего. Как их можно отождествлять?

Comment: Вы предлагаете убить автора? А что ещё остаётся? Розенталя он читать не будет, факт. Вот нельзя отрывать эпоху от её определения - *эпоха христианского искусства*, нельзя читать по два-три слова и искать в них логику. Да мы здесь и не за этим...

Comment: Но мы должны защищать великий и могучий от попыток превратить его в набор не связанных между собой слов. А автора приговорить к трем годам усиленного чтения Розенталя! – М_Г 3 минуты назад   править

Comment: Это решает издатель - там свои эксперты. Текст может и не пойти в набор. Сейчас - первая корректура-редактура по практически черновику.

Answer (score 1):

Не поняла, откуда  ***тире*** и местоимение ***это***. Может быть, нужно просто продолжить перечисление?

Вместо того чтобы сказать: внимание к подробности, стремление к идейной концентрации, натурализм, величие, монументальность (которая может таиться и в маленькой вещичке), **а также мощь и сила,** лаконичность высказывания, максимальная обращённость к зрителю, – чтобы всего этого не говорить, говорят просто: римское искусство.

Comment: Ни! Я тута разобралася: "внимание к подробности, стремление к идейной концентрации, натурализм, величие, монументальность (которая может таиться и в маленькой вещичке) – это мощь и сила, лаконичность высказывания, максимальная обращённость к зрителю". И вот, ***чтобы всего этого не говорить, говорят просто: римское искусство***. )))

Comment: Может быть, хотя мне это тождество не очень понятно.

Comment: Ну, извините, так нельзя. **Вместо того, чтобы сказать: А это Б, говорят В**?! Где логика? Я уж не говорю о том, что у вас между А и Б мало общего. Как их можно отождествлять?

Answer (score 0):

Есть стилистические и пунктуационные ошибки. Предложения громоздки, читаются и воспринимаются плохо, надо перечитать, чтобы понять и вникнуть.
Вот мой вариант:

> Цитата

Помимо того, что Рим дал название целой эпохе христианского искусства, романское (X–XIII столетия), есть и такое понятие - римское искусство. Этот термин специалисты нередко употребляют, подразумевая под ним целый набор качеств и свойств художественного произведения. Вместо того, чтобы сказать: «внимание к подробности, стремление к идейной концентрации, натурализм, величие, монументальность, которая может таиться и в маленькой вещичке, а также мощь, сила, лаконичность высказывания и максимальная обращённость к зрителю», говорят просто: римское искусство.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, пунктуационные ошибки. А то я, редактор сего текста, их не вижу.

Comment: Помимо того, что Рим дал название целой эпохе христианского искусства, романское (X–XIII столетия), есть и такое понятие - римское искусство. Этот термин специалисты нередко употребляют, подразумевая под ним целый набор качеств и свойств художественного произведения. Вместо того, чтобы сказать: «внимание к подробности, стремление к идейной концентрации, натурализм, величие, монументальность, которая может таиться и в маленькой вещичке, а также мощь, сила, лаконичность высказывания и максимальная обращённость к зрителю», говорят просто: римское искусство.      http://rosental-book.ru/

Comment: Ну, *помимо того, что* и *вместо того, чтобы* - это ***внесённые Вами ошибки***; а двоеточие или тире после *есть и такое понятие* - это вмешательство в авторскую пунктуацию, беспричинное. То же относится и к авторским скобкам. И если мы вместо условного знака равенства, выраженного словом "это", напишем "а также", то просто исказим авторскую мысль. То есть вместо помощи автору изобразим что-то своё, в то время как издатель хочет послушать именно этого автора, за тем его и пригласил.

Comment: Спасибо, повеселили...